# invoke methods from .so files residing in project folder from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, java-native-library

I have developed a plugin for Eclipse which has to access native libraries.

Is it mandatory that the .so file resides in `/usr/lib` for the plugin to access it? Unless it is present there, my plugin cannot access the methods within it. I need my plugin to access the .so within itself so that even when I deploy the plugin, it should work without any configuration changes. I have used `System.loadLibrary()` to load the .so but even when I loaded the library using its full path in `System.load()`, it didn't work unless I copy the .so file to `/usr/lib`.

How can I make my plugin access it from its own source folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Bundle-NativeCode directive to your MANIFEST.MF. Here are a couple of links on how to formulate it:

[Secrets of Bundle-NativeCode](http://litrik.blogspot.com/2007/08/secrets-of-bundle-nativecode.html)

[Bundle-NativeCode in the OSGi manifest](http://robertvarttinen.blogspot.com/2008/12/bundle-nativecode-in-osgi-manifest.html)

Note that the path you give in the directive is relative to your plugin directory structure. E.g., '/mylibrary.so' means the file is in root directory of your plugin.